# Flow not triggering from User object

Tags: visual-workflow, user-record

I've got a autolaunched flow on the user object (create/update).  The flow should run when user updates their profile picture but, for some reason, doesn't.

In debug mode, the flow runs all the appropriates steps (get records, updates records) with the correct values yet, it doesn't seem to fire when I update the User record's profile picture.

Any ideas why the Flow won't trigger?

Answer (score 3):

It's not an issue with the Flow, but the fact that **updating the user's profile picture doesn't run any triggers for User**. The same applies to the banner photo.

You can quickly test this with apex triggers and debug logs (*none will be generated*). You'll also note the `LastModifiedDate` does not change if you just change the photo.

In terms of documentation, it's not explicitly called out (though [others](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BLb1IAG) have noted this [behavior](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BKdJIAW)) but I believe the issue is due to the fact that the fields on [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) that correspond to the User photo are *derived* fields from the [Photo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_pictures.htm) record ([prefix](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325244&type=1): 729) that contains the image. Similar to how a formula field wouldn't trigger an update on a given object if its related object value changes.

- FullPhotoUrl
- SmallPhotoUrl
- BannerPhotoUrl
- MediumBannerPhotoUrl
- SmallBannerPhotoUrl

You see mention of this in the [Change Event Message Structure](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_message_structure.htm)

> The fields that a change event doesn’t include are:
>
> - The IsDeleted system field.
> - The SystemModStamp system field.
> - Any **field
>   whose value isn’t on the record and is derived** from another record or
>   from a formula, except roll-up summary fields, which are included.
>   Examples are formula fields. **Examples of fields with derived values**
>   include LastActivityDate and **PhotoUrl**

Comment: Very interesting.  Thanks for sharing this valuable insight!  Given this, would my only choice be to run a scheduled triggered flow (periodically) to grab the latest FullPhotoUrl for all profiles and update?  Seems like it would be a waste of resources...

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to be the only option (scheduled apex/flow) if you do need to update something based on user photo. I'm not sure what you're updating based on the photo, but I would consider how often you'd need to run it as that could get unwieldy easily - especially if you use scheduled flow.